# R dismo threshold() returns negative values

Tags: r, modelling, dismo

I model tree species in R using various models (glm, gam, brt). For evaluating their prediction I run following code after my model calibration.

```
#threshold version 1
##calculating ideal cut-off value to separate presence and absence predictions

thresh_test = dismo::threshold(dismo::evaluate(presence_test, absence_test, model))
##optimal threshold value =-0.1236 which is quite unrealistic

eval = dismo::evaluate(presence_test, absence_test, model, tr=thresh_test$kappa)
print(eval@kappa)

tp 
0.5677312
```

For comparison I run a function of the biomod2 package

```
#threshold version 2
species=mySelectedTreeSpecies
##caluclating TSS maximising cut-off value

thresh_test = Find.Optim.Stat(Stat='KAPPA', model$fitted.values, test[ , species])
##optimal threshold value = 0 which is quite unrealistic
#thresh_test[2] holds the kappa maximiser cut-off value to separate presence and absence predictions

eval = dismo::evaluate(presence_test, absence_test, model, tr=thresh_test[2])
print(eval@kappa)

tp 
0.5617641
```

Both of these methods return similar and realistic cohen's kappa values. But the threshold of my version 1 for all of my models (gam, glm, brt) is a negative value. The threshold of verion 2 is 0. Do you know this issue?

For clarity - I model with > 4mio. train and >800000 test data with a lot more absence than presence data. Could that be the issue of my negative threshold values?

Answer (score 0):

Found my error! 
The `dismo::evaluate` function runs a prediction internally if certain criteria is met with input data (if not a vector) and one needs to specify `type='response'` as it returns values on the log-odds scale otherwise.

```
thresh_test = dismo::threshold(dismo::evaluate(p=presence_test, a=absence_test, model=model, type='response'))
##optimal threshold value = 0.412072

eval = dismo::evaluate(p=presence_test, a=absence_test, model=model, type='response', tr=thresh_test$kappa)
```